# ReferenceError: command is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord

I am trying to create a `richEmbed` command for Discord Bot using JavaScript.

My prefix is "."

When I try to run the following code I get this error; `command is not defined`.

My command should be: `.completed`

This is my code for Discord Bot on which I need help to make it run successfully.

```
const discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  if (command === `${prefix}completed`) {

    var userIcon = message.member.user.displayAvatarURL;

    //try
    const words = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');

    //check for input
    if (!words.length) {
      return message.channel.send(`You did not provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`);
    }
    if (!words.length > 7) {
      return message.channel.send(`You provided too many arguments,  ${message.author}!`);
    }

    //split
    var goldPot = words[5];
    var goldLocation = words[6];

    //maths
    var goldPotInt = parseInt(goldPot);
    var boosterCut = goldPotInt * 0.178;
    var totBooCut = boosterCut * 4;
    var advertCut = goldPotInt * 0.173;
    var guildCut = goldPotInt * 0.115;

    //print
    var botEmbed = new discord.RichEmbed()
      .setDescription("M+ Completed")
      .setColor("#8e12db")
      .setThumbnail(userIcon)
      .addField("Booster 1 " + message.mentions.users.first())
      .addField("Booster 2 " + message.mentions.users.second())
      .addField("Booster 3 " + message.mentions.users.third())
      .addField("Booster 4 " + message.mentions.users.forth())
      .addField("Pot of Gold " + goldPot + "k")

      .addField("Total Booster Cut" + totBooCut + "k")
      .addField("Indi. Booster Cut" + boosterCut + "k")
      .addField("Advertiser Cut" + advertCut + "k")
      .addField("Guild Cut" + guildCut + "k")

      .addField("Location of Gold " + goldLocation)
      .addField("Advertiser " + message.mentions.users.fifth());

    return message.channel.send(botEmbed);
  }

}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "completed"
}
```

Comment: Yes that's obvious, because `command` is not defined in the file.

Comment: Sorry, i'm very new to this. Where do i need to define it and how? @SonuBamniya , I've been getting this stuff from tutorials but this is how far i get

Comment: I think you meant to use some part of the `message` variable,eg `message.content.includes(\`${prefix}completed\`)` or whatever actually contains the incoming text from user

Comment: @PatrickEvans You mean like this? I only posted a small part of the whole code

const discord = require("discord.js");



    module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {

        if (message.content.includes(`${prefix}completed`)) {
            

            var userIcon = message.member.user.displayAvatarURL;